# Change my header size based on the user scrolling

Tags: react-native

As i scroll down my flatlist, i would like my HeaderArea to reduce in size. I have an animation in place to do this that responds to the scrolling of the Y axis.

The `this.animatedHeaderHeight` picks up my start and end header height fine, but when i scroll up and down in the flatllist, the header doesn't change it's height whatsoever! Please help, what am i doing wrong?

```
 export default class MyClass extends Component {
    
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {

        columns: 3, //Columns for Grid

         /***** Animated scrolling hide header info ****/
         scrollY:  new Animated.Value(0),

         startHeaderHeight: 250, //(ITEM_HEIGHT/4),
         endHeaderHeight: 50, //(ITEM_HEIGHT/      
       
  
    };

}
    
    
        render() {
     
            const animatedHeaderHeight = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
 
               inputRange: [0,50],
               outputRange: [this.state.startHeaderHeight, this.state.endHeaderHeight],
               extraploate: 'clamp'
            })

          return (
    
    
             <SafeAreaView style={styles.profileContainer}> 
    
                 <Animated.View style={[styles.HeaderArea, { height: animatedHeaderHeight, backgroundColor: 'orange' }]}>         
    
                               <View style={styles.uploaderPic}>
                                   <Text> HELLO </Text>
                                </View>  
                    
                 </Animated.View>
                 <View style={styles.grid}>
                     <ScrollView scrollEventThrottle={16}>
    
                         <FlatList
                                numColumns={columns}
                  
                                data={myArray}  
    
                                onScroll={Animated.event(
                                    [{nativeEvent:{contentOffset: {y:this.state.scrollY}}},
                                    {useNativeDriver: true} ]
                                )}
                                keyExtractor={   (item, index) => { return index }   }
                                renderItem=
                                       ..............
                                          />        
                                          )
                                  }} 
                               
                          />
                     </ScrollView>
                 </View> 
           </SafeAreaView>
      )
    }
    
    
    

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    profileContainer: {
      flex: 1,

    },
    HeaderArea: {

    },
    uploaderPic: {

    },
    grid: {
      flex: 3,
      flexDirection: 'column',
    },

  });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use a Flatlist or a ScrollView and its initialize your variables inside of `constructer` rather than `componentWillMount`.

This is how i did it using your code.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.scrollY = new Animated.Value(0);

    this.startHeaderHeight = 250; //(ITEM_HEIGHT/4)
    this.endHeaderHeight = 50; //(ITEM_HEIGHT/7)

    this.animatedHeaderHeight = this.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 50],
      outputRange: [this.startHeaderHeight, this.endHeaderHeight],
      extraploate: 'clamp'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.HeaderArea,
            { height: this.animatedHeaderHeight, backgroundColor: 'orange' }
          ]}>
          <View style={styles.uploaderPic}>
            <Text> HELLO </Text>
          </View>
        </Animated.View>

        <FlatList
          data={[
            'adsa',
            'dsa',
            'dsa',
            'dsa',
            'dsa',
            'dsa',
            'Dsa',
            'Dsa',
            'Dsa'
          ]}
          onScroll={Animated.event([
            { nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.scrollY } } }
          ])}
          renderItem={() => (
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 100 }}>
              <Text>abc</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  profileContainer: {
    flex: 1
  },
  HeaderArea: {},
  uploaderPic: {},
  grid: {
    flex: 3,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  }
});
```

Comment: I edited the original post to initialise the variables in the Constructor, not ComponentWillMount(). It's still not workin. Can you spot the mistake?

Comment: We should not keep animated values in the state.
is it not working for you using my code?

Comment: you still have flatlist inside of the scrollView. You need to have either flatlist or scrollView and you also need to move out the animated values from the state of the component...Please try with my code...its working fine with it. You can let me know the issue you are getting in that.